# Imagem linux em Docker?

Tags: docker

Estou tentando entender o conceito de *Docker* mas ainda está meio confuso para mim. *Docker* seria um gerador/emulador de imagem que pode ser gerenciada em nuvem? Se for isso, acredito que eu tenha entendido.

Mas a questão é, se for realmente isso, não estou entendendo como funciona. Como devo fazer para puxar uma imagem e rodar ela no *Docker*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe duas formas de criar imagens customizadas com **commit** e com **dockerfile**.

> **Commit:**

Precisamos primeiro criar um container qualquer:

```
docker run -it --name containername ubuntu:16.04 bash
```

Agora que estamos no bash do container, vamos instalar o nginx nele:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nginx -y
exit
```

Vamos parar o container com o comando abaixo:

```
docker stop containername
```

Agora vamos efetuar o commit desse container em uma imagem:

```
docker commit containername meuubuntu:nginx
```

`containername` é o nome do container que criamos e modificamos nos passos anteriores e o nome `meuubuntu:nginx` é a imagem resultante do commit, ou seja, o estado do `containername` será armazenado em uma imagem chamada `meuubuntu:nginx` que nesse caso a única modificação que temos da imagem oficial do *ubuntu* na versão 16.04 é um pacote `nginx` instalado.

Para visualizar a lista de imagens e encontrar a que acabou de criar, execute novamente o comando abaixo:

```
docker images
```

Para testar sua nova imagem, vamos criar um `container` a partir dela e verificar se o `nginx` está instalado:

```
docker run -it --rm meuubuntu:nginx dpkg -l nginx
```

Se quiser validar, pode executar o mesmo comando na imagem oficial do *ubuntu*:

```
docker run -it --rm ubuntu:16.04 dpkg -l nginx
```

Vale salientar que o método commit não é a melhor opção para criar imagens, pois como pudemos verificar, o processo de modificação da imagem é completamente manual e apresenta certa dificuldade para rastrear as mudanças que foram efetuadas, uma vez que o que foi modificado manualmente não é registrado automaticamente na estrutura do docker.

> **DockerFile**

Primeiro crie um arquivo qualquer para um teste futuro:

```
touch arquivo_teste
```

Crie um arquivo chamado `Dockerfile` e dentro dele coloque o seguinte conteúdo:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nginx -y
COPY arquivo_teste /tmp/arquivo_teste
CMD bash
```

No arquivo acima eu utilizei quatro instruções:

**FROM** é usado para informar qual imagem usada como base, nesse caso foi a *Ubuntu 16.04*.

**RUN** é usado para informar quais comandos serão executados nesse ambiente para efetuar as mudanças necessárias na infraestrutura do sistema. São como comandos executados no shell do ambiente, igual ao modelo por commit, mas nesse caso foi efetuado automaticamente e completamente rastreável, já que esse *Dockerfile* será armazenado no sistema de controle de versão.

**COPY** é usado para copiar arquivos da estação onde está executando a construção para dentro da imagem. Usamos um arquivo de teste apenas para exemplificar essa possibilidade, mas essa instrução é muito utilizada para enviar arquivos de configuração de ambiente e códigos para serem executados em serviços de aplicação.

**CMD** é usado informar qual comando será executado por padrão, caso nenhum seja informado na inicialização de um container a partir dessa imagem. No nosso caso colocamos o comando bash, ou seja, caso essa imagem seja usada para iniciar um container e não informamos o comando, ele executará o bash.

Após construir seu Dockerfile basta executar o comando abaixo:

```
docker build -t meuubuntu:nginx_auto .
```

O comando acima tem a opção `-t` que serve para informar o nome da imagem que será criada, que no nosso caso `meuubuntu:nginx_auto` e o `.` no final informa qual o contexto que deve ser usado nessa construção de imagem, ou seja, todos os arquivos da sua pasta atual serão enviados para o serviço do *docker* e apenas eles podem ser usados para manipulações do *Dockerfile* (Exemplo do uso do COPY).

O resultado de cada instrução desse arquivo é armazenado em um cache local, ou seja, caso o *Dockerfile* não seja modificado na próxima criação da imagem (build) o processo não demorará, pois tudo estará no cache, mas caso algo seja modificado apenas a instrução modificada e as posteriores serão executadas novamente.

A sugestão para aproveitar bem o cache do Dockerfile é sempre manter instruções que mudem com mais frequência mais próximas da base do documento. Vale lembrar de atender também as dependências entre instruções.

Vamos utilizar um exemplo para deixar mais claro:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nginx
RUN apt-get install php5
COPY arquivo_teste /tmp/arquivo_teste
CMD bash
```

Caso modifiquemos a terceira linha do arquivo e ao invés de instalar o `nginx` mudarmos para `apache2`, a instrução que faz o `update` no `apt` não será executada novamente, mas a instalação do `apache2` será instalado, pois acabou de entrar no arquivo, assim como o `php5` e a cópia do arquivo, pois todos eles são subsequentes a linha modificada.

> Dê uma boa olhada no site do [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/push-images/) têm muita informação que procura ou então [aqui](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-e-utilizar-o-docker-primeiros-passos-pt), fonte: [TechFree](http://techfree.com.br/2016/03/criando-sua-propria-imagem-docker/)